# How to indicate warnings inside of parLapply function

Tags: r, parallel-processing, warnings, statistics-bootstrap

I am constructing bootstrap function that will estimate logistic regression on each bootstrapped data set and do some additional calculations. For small samples sometimes it may produce warnings such as

```
Warning messages:
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
```

I would like to indicate such warnings for each bootstrap iteration.
Here is my code:

```
library(parallel)

n=length(y);
dataN=as.matrix((cbind(y,data)));
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterExport(cl,c("dataN"), envir=environment())
clusterExport(cl,c("n"), envir=environment())
clusterEvalQ(cl,library(glmnet))
q=2000;
repl1=parLapply(cl=cl,1:q,function(i,dataA=dataN,smpl=n,...){
  dataB <- dataA[sample(nrow(dataA),size=smpl,replace=TRUE),]
  p=dim(dataB)[2];p
  forname=c(colnames(dataB)[2:p]);
  formulaZS=as.formula(paste("y~",paste(forname,collapse="+"),sep=""));
  assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())
  m=glm(formulaZS,family=binomial,data=data.frame(dataB))
  coefs=summary(m)$coef[,1];coefs
  a=length(attr(warnings(),"names"))
  indicator=ifelse(a==0,0,1);
  return(list(coefs=coefs,indicator=indicator))
})  
stopCluster(cl)

beta=t(matrix(unlist(lapply(repl1, "[[", "coefs")),nrow=p+1));
beta.est=apply(beta,2,mean);beta.est
indicator=t(matrix(unlist(lapply(repl1, "[[", "indicator")),nrow=1));
sum(indicator)
```

Before each regression estimation I'm resetting warnings by

```
assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv())
```

and then checking if there was warning by calculating the length of `warnings()` names. This works if I'm doing it manually, without application of `parLapply`. However, if I'm running this function it produces the vector `indicator` with only zeroes even if there were warnings.

Data generating code:

```
fundata=function(n,p,corr){
      R = matrix(rep(corr,p*p),nrow=p)+(1-corr)*diag(p);
      R <- round(((R * lower.tri(R)) + t(R * lower.tri(R))),2)
      diag(R) <- 1 
      U = t(chol(R))
      nvars = dim(U)[1]
      random.normal = matrix(rnorm(nvars*n,mean=0,sd=1), nrow=nvars, ncol=n);
      X = U %*% random.normal
      newX = t(X)
      data = as.data.frame(newX)
      names(data)<-sprintf("V%d",1:p)
      return(data=data) 
}
n=50;
p=5;
corr=0.5;
seed=123;
#Generate independent variables
data=fundata(n,p,corr);
#Generate dependent variable
p=dim(data)[2];p
  true=c(-1,0,0,0.2,0.675,-1.5)
  z=as.matrix(cbind(rep(1,n),data[,1:p]))%*%true;
  pr = 1/(1+exp(-z));
  y = rbinom(n=n, size=1, prob=t(pr))
  dataN=as.matrix((cbind(y,data)))
```

Comment: A work around for your specific situation is to check if any of the coefs are larger than 12-15 in absolute terms. On the logit scale, this corresponds to about infinity, indicating that the model has run into problems.

Comment: Can you provide the data so that we can run your code?

Comment: @F.Privé Sure. I have added it.

Comment: @HongOoi I did that before, but it is very inaccurate solution. I would like to know in general if it is possible to track warnings inside of parallel programming functions, tag them and respond with a suitable strategy.

Comment: Error in matrix(rep(corr, p * p), nrow = p) : 
  argument "corr" is missing, with no default

Comment: @F.Privé Fixed. The original code is much longer, so I tried to leave only  the necessary code and forgot to define correlation. But you can put any non-zero correlation smaller than |0.7|...it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Error in as.matrix(cbind(rep(1, n), data[, 1:p])) %*% true : 
  non-conformable arguments. Is it really that difficult to open a new session and try running your code before posting it here?

Comment: @F.Privé Fixed.